How can cesium determine whether the asynchronous primitives has been drawn
How can cesium determine whether the asynchronous primitives has been drawn,just like loading model like gltf having an api called readyPromise,but sample primitives have no such func.
The primitive has a prop named 'ready',but it doesn't work.Here is my code.
const addPrimitive = async (
    instance: any,
    viewer: Cesium.Viewer,
    callback: Function
  ) => {
    var primitive = new Cesium.Primitive({
      geometryInstances: instance,
      appearance: new Cesium.PerInstanceColorAppearance({
        flat: true,
        translucent: true,
      }),
      asynchronous: true,
    });

    var model = await viewer.scene.primitives.add(primitive);
    console.log(model);
    console.log(model.ready);
  };

model.ready in console is always false,but 'ready' prop of model in console is true,I can't figure out what happened.
